# Which is the better way to create my mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

Based on my situation, should I combine all symptoms into one row as my method 1 below or method 2 that create more rows. The reason I don't like method 1 is that I have to use - to separate each symptom, and later I need to use php explode('-') to separate them and use LIKE to match them.

Method 2 will create more rows, and I think I will create more table to separate them.

Method 1:

```
disease           symptoms
HIV               pain-cough-hair loss
Flu               cought-running nose-fever
cacer             lose weight-fever-fatigue
```

Method 2:

```
disease       symptoms
HIV           pain
HIV           cough     
HIV           hair loss
...           ...
...           ...
```

Comment: Method 2. It's very rare that storing more than one value in a single field doesn't end in misery and regret.

Comment: I think I can I use DISTINCT to solve this problem, can I ?

Comment: Distinct to solve which problem? The issue is proper normalization and, separately, future scale. Just imagine if you wanted to start storing attributes of symptoms a year from now and you go with method1. You'll end up with a join from hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of your two methods, method 2 would be preferred. As *@JNevill* notes, storing multiple pieces of data in one column becomes a nightmare when searching or filtering data.

My full recommendation would be to use option 3 however. Take a look at the below design:

**Table 1:** DISEASES

```
+------+-----------+
|  id  |  name     |
+------+-----------+
|    1 | HIV       |
|------|-----------|
|    2 | FLU       |
|------|-----------|
|    3 | Cancer    |
+------+-----------+
```

Primary Key:

- `id`

**Table 2:** SYMPTOMS

```
+------+-----------+
|  id  |  name     |
+------+-----------+
|    1 |  pain     |
|------|-----------|
|    2 | cough     |
|------|-----------|
|    3 | hair-loss |
+------+-----------+
```

Primary Key:

- `id`

**Table 3:** DISEASES-SYMPTOMS

```
+-------------+--------------+
|  disease_id  |  symptom_id  |
+--------------+--------------+
|           1  |           1  |
|--------------|--------------|
|           1  |           2  |
|--------------|--------------|
|           1  |           3  |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Primary Key:

- `(disease_id, symptom_id)`

Foreign Keys:

- `DISEASES.id` -> `DISEASES_SYMTPOMS.disease_id`
- `SYMTPOMS.id` -> `DISEASES_SYMTPOMS.symptom_id`

Establish your base tables `DISEASES` and `SYMPTOMS`. Then establish a 3<sup>rd</sup> table representing a `JOIN` of the first two tables. This normalization of the data will simply the structure of your application and prevent duplication of data since each disease can have multiple symptoms and each symptom can belong to multiple disease.

**SAMPLE QUERY (MySQL):**

```
SELECT
d.id,
d.name,
s.name
FROM DISEASES as d
INNER JOIN DISEASES_SYMPTOMS AS ds ON d.id = ds.disease_id
INNER JOIN SYMPTOMS AS s ON ds.symptom_id = s.id;
```

**SAMPLE QUERY RESULT:**

```
+------+----------------+----------------+
|  id  |  disease_name  |  symptom_name  |
+------+----------------+----------------+
|   1  | HIV            |  pain          |
|------|----------------|----------------|
|   1  | HIV            |  cough         |
|------|----------------|----------------|
|   1  | HIV            |  hair-loss     |
+------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how normalized you want your database to be. The more normalized approach would be to create a symptoms table that houses all symptoms, a disease table that houses all diseases, and another table with links diseases to symptoms probably by disease_id and symptom_id. And the less normalized approach is like your method 1 where you include all the symptoms as a field in the table separated by some delimiter or put into an array if you are using a database that supports arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Create two `master tables` for `disease` & `symptoms`. And then create a third table say .`disease_symptom` include the two foreign key column say `disease_id` & `symptom_id` and refer to the corresponding master table